# How can open directly a modalbox from a hyperlink in Bootsrap?

Tags: url, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, bootstrap-modal

I made a website where every section open in a modalbox, and i need that the section into the modelbox open when I click the url section from other website. example, my website is http://corpetrol.com/ you can open a section clickiing in the buttons (ex. "Educamos con calidad"), but i would like that the section auto open clicking on section url (http://corpetrol.com/educamos-con-calidad). I use the last bootstrap version

Comment: Do you mean that if someone enters the [URL educamos-con-calidad](http://corpetrol.com/educamos-con-calidad) it should look exactly like if he enters the url of the [startpage](http://corpetrol.com/) and then clicks on the link for item col6 ("corpetrol-sedes")?

Comment: ... Should look exactly as if he enters the url of the startpage and then clicks the link for "Educamos con calidad".

Comment: What do you have available in your back-end? You need server-side software to look for the referrer and display the startpage from other urls if they are accessed directly; or to redirect to the startpage with some reference to the requested url or content, which you would then grab and load into the modal.

Comment: @marlenunez, the server have php, and the website was made with [http://get-simple.info/](http://get-simple.info/) a cms